# WinEdt 10.2: where is the spell-checker settings?

Tags: winedt, spelling

I am using WinEdt 10.2 and I find its spell-checker quite irregular in underlining syntax errors. (I write in English.)
While it can usually detect my syntax errors, there are instances when it ignores blatant mistakes. Has anyone seen a similar thing? Is there any solution to this issue?

Plus, where (in the toolbars for example) can I find the spell-checker settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the settings of the spell-checking system, you have to modify the corresponding configuration files.

You can open these files from the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface) under the "Dictionary Manager" branch:

[image]

To achieve your requirements, you would have the need to modify some properties of the following:

- Spelling Options
- Ignored Text
- Misspelled Words
- Compounded Words

In the manual, select "WinEdt Configuration Manual" -> "Dictionary Manager" to have help on the properties listed in these files.

[image]